# TaskDefinition CDK and LogConfiguration

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I am trying to accomplish the following

> If you are using the Fargate launch type for your tasks, all you need to do to turn on the awslogs log driver is add the required logConfiguration parameters to your task definition.

I am using CDK to generate the FargateTaskDefn

```
task_definition = _ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, "TaskDefinition",
                                                 cpu=2048,
                                                 memory_limit_mib=4096,
                                                 execution_role=ecs_role,
                                                 task_role = ecs_role,
                                                 )
    task_definition.add_container("getFileTask",
                                  memory_limit_mib = 4096,
                                  cpu=2048,
                                  image = _ecs.ContainerImage.from_asset(directory="assets", file="Dockerfile-ecs-file-download"))
```

I looked up the documentation and did not find the any attribute called logConfiguration.

What am I missing?

I am not able to send the logs from Container running on ECS/Fargate to Cloudwatch and what is needed is to enable this logConfiguration option in the task defn.

Thank you for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that Logging option in add_container is the one.

Comment: And what was your written solution then?